# Firebase sincronizar solo datos de la empresa

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo alrededor de 200 empresas que utilizarán la app (android). Pero no quiero que firebase sincronice todos los datos de todas las empresas.

En el ejemplo, quiero que todos los usuarios de la empresa 1, sincronicen unicamente las ventas de la empresa 1.

```
{
  "ventas": [
    {
      "empresa": "empresa 1",
      "producto": "producto 1",
      "usuario": "usuario 1"
    },
    {
      "empresa": "empresa 2",
      "producto": "producto 2",
      "usuario": "usuario 2"
    },
    {
      "empresa": "empresa 1",
      "producto": "producto 3",
      "usuario": "usuario 3"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso podrías [aplicar un filtro](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) y solo devolver la ventas que cumplan con la condición de ser de la empresa que consulta.

Pero si tu agrupador son las empresas creo que tendría más sentido un modelo donde el nodo sean las empresas y cada empresa tenga un nodo con sus ventas.